# ui-router test failed with event.preventDefault() in $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I have problem with my angular test.

```
describe('Routes test', function() {
    //Initialize global variables
    var $state,
        $location;

    // Load the main application module
    beforeEach(module("MyApp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$location_, _$state_, $templateCache) {
        $state = _$state_;
        $location = _$location_;

        // We need add the template entry into the templateCache if we ever
        // specify a templateUrl
        $templateCache.put('signin.admin.view.html', 'signin');
    }));

    it('should be redirect to signin if user is not loggedin', function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $location.path('/');
        });
        expect($state.current.name).toEqual('signin');
        console.log($state.current);
    });
});
```

So I expect signin state because user is not logged in. But from console $state.current is still:

```
Object{name: '', url: '^', views: null, abstract: true}
```

To redirect I used this code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.name.indexOf('signin') === 0 ) {
        if( loggedIn ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('layout.dashboard');
        }
    } else {
        if( !loggedIn ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('signin');
        }
    }
});
```

Variable loggedIn is false. So I dont understand, when I make test manually in browser $state.current is as expected. But not in this test.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing `$rootScope.$apply(...)` try doing:

```
$location.path('/');
$rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess');
```

UI Router listens to the `$locationChangeSuccess` event that is fired from angular's `$location` service. When it catches this event it will find the correct state and begin navigating to that state, hence firing the `$stateChangeStart` event.

Hope this helps!